# count the times a certain key name shows up in a multi-array?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, count

How may I count the times a key shows up in a multi-array?

In the below example, `weight` should return 2, and `reps` 4. Does PHP have a built-in function for this?

```
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [weight] => 317.51474856007
                                [reps] => 10
                            )

                        [1] => Array
                            (
                                [weight] => 50
                                [reps] => 10
                            )

                        [2] => Array
                            (
                                [reps] => 10
                            )

                        [3] => Array
                            (
                                [reps] => 10
                            )

                    )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one liner using [**array_walk_recursive()**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php):

Given your array, `$arr`

```
array_walk_recursive($arr, function($v, $k)use(&$count){if(array_key_exists($k, $count))$count[$k]++;else $count[$k]=1;},$count=array());
print_r($count);
```

[**See demo**](http://3v4l.org/VrZ0l)

or the old fashioned way:

```
$count = array();
foreach ($arr as $ar){
    foreach ($ar as $k=>$v){
        if (array_key_exists($k, $count)){
            $count[$k]++;
        }
        else{
            $count[$k] = 1;
        }
    }
}
print_r($count);
```

[**See demo**](http://codepad.org/p1wyRgFh)

Output:

```
Array
(
    [weight] => 2
    [reps] => 4
)
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try something like this:

```
function counter($array){
    $result = array();
    foreach($array as $key=>$value){
        foreach($value as $name => $val){
            $result[$name][]=$val;
        }
    }
    return array('all'=>$result,'count weight'=>count($result['weight']),'count reps'=>count($result['reps']));
}

$array= Array(
    '0' => Array
    (
    'weight' => 317.51474856007,
    'reps' => 10
    ),

    '1' => Array
    (
    'weight' => 50,
    'reps' => 10
    ),

    '2' => Array
    (
    'reps' => 12
    ),

    '3' => Array
    (
    'reps' => 10
    )
);


$resp = counter($array);   

var_dump($resp);
```

Comment: I liked the return $result from the function better because it didn't matter what keys were used. From this I was going to expand with: foreach($resp as $key => $value){ echo $key . ': ' . count($value) . ' times.<br />';}

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
$array= Array(
                        '0' => Array
                            (
                                'weight' => 317.51474856007,
                                'reps' => 10
                            ),

                        '1' => Array
                            (
                                'weight' => 50,
                                'reps' => 10
                            ),

                        '2' => Array
                            (
                                'reps' => 10
                            ),

                        '3' => Array
                            (
                                'reps' => 10
                            )

                    );
$weight=0;
$reps=0;
//print_r($array);
foreach($array as $key=>$val){

    if(isset($val['weight'])){
        echo $val['weight']."<br>";
        $weight++;
    }
    if(isset($val['reps'])){
        echo $val['reps']."<br>";
        $resp++;
    }

}

echo $weight."   ".$resp;
```